# How compile a java file to .class who use others .class. (if it's possible)

Tags: java, android, jar, .class-file

I get lib webrtc in a `.aar`, and I need to modify one file of this lib.
We can call this file `tomtom.class` for this example

So I unzip this `.aar` to get many `.jar` and in those `.jar` there the file `tomtom.class` who need to be replaced.
I have the new version of file tomtom in java because I edit it. But now I need to compile it for replacing the old `tomtom.class`. Of course, this file uses other classes inside this lib webrtc.

So is it possible to compile a java file who use other compiled file?

Comment: simply set your preferred java compiler's classpath to (where ever all your other class files are)

Comment: The answer is yes. There is a way to find out the answer for yourself at absolutely no cost!

Comment: I tried to do this : `javac -classpath "/Users/boris/libwebrtc.aar/libwebrtc/org/webrtc/"  HardwareVideoEncoderFactory.java`. But that doesn't work : it don 't find the other class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tried of use classpath. Or other method I find on Internet. 
None work, maybe it's me who is a moron but whatever..

How I replaced my file on a lib already compiled (it's the webrtc lib).

I put a copy of the file decompiled in my project on android studio. I can modify it like I want. And this decompiled file can compile with the lib I had in the folder lib. 
I build the project and I go to the temp file to get the compiled file. 
Then I can replace the one in .aar by the file compiled I just modify.